# Estado HTTP 500 - Error Parsing /index.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 20] The element type "h:form" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</h:form>"

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm starting with PrimeFaces following an example of Youtube, and when I run my application reference error appears.

My environment is as follows:
Server: Tomcat 7.0.50
JavaServerFaces: 2.2.9
PrimeFaces: 5.2
IDE: Eclipse Moon

My "web.xml" code is as follows:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>PrimeFacesVenta</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
<description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
<param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
<param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
<param-value>resources.application</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
<listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
</web-app>
```

The code of my "index.xhtml" file is as follows:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<h:title>Insert title here</h:title>
</h:head>
<h:body>

<h:form>
    <p:outputLabel value="Nombre" />
    <p:inputText value="#{personaBean.persona.nombre}" />

    <p:outputLabel for="Sexo" value="Basic:" />
        <p:selectOneMenu id="sexo" value="#{personaBean.persona.sexo}" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="MASCULINO" itemValue="M" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="FEMENINO" itemValue="F" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

You see, the  it is properly closed with , so I do not understand what happens.

I appreciate any help you can give me.

Greetings!

Gustavo Echenique

Comment: This is just a XML syntax error. You closed one tag twice. This has technically nothing to do with JSF nor PrimeFaces. Take a pause, get some sleep, tomorrow is a new day to program. By the way, tutorials written by amateurs are more than often much worse than tutorials and books written by authoritative experts. You've been warned.

Comment: I'll add that in my experience more often the error isn't in the tag you see in the error message but rather in between. It makes sens.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was in the following line:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="sexo" value="#{personaBean.persona.sexo}" />
```

The terminator tag "/>" was causing the error, and that it should be ">" only.

I hope you serve others.